# Can i connect to my MySql Server using workbench without having a password

Tags: mysql-workbench, password-protection, windows-firewall

I have a MySql database that is running on a linux server. The DB is not password encrypted. 
I understand that no password != empty password.
I installed mysql workbenck on my windows laptop and am trying to connect to my database. It doesn't allow me to. 
Details:
Connection method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Error: Cannot connect to Database server
Your connection attempt failed for user'root' from your host to server at 3306
Host is not allowed to connect to this MySql Server.
I am supposing it might be a windows firewall issue. 
Please can somebody help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it clearly: the machine you are connecting from is not allowed to connect. In a MySQL server you can create users with specific IPs they can connect from. Often only localhost access is enabled (user@localhost or user@127.0.0.1 or user@::1), sometimes anyhost (user@%). In order to connect from your Windows machine your user must either be allowed to connect from any host or you need a specific user for the IP address of your Win machine.

Answer (score 0):

The error because the mysql server is not starting in your computer.so you can start it manually..do the following steps,
1.download and install wamp server according to your bit version(32bit or 64bit) in your       computer(http://wampserver-64bit.en.softonic.com/) this link allows you to download wamp server for 64bit.

2.As soon as you install it you can double click and run it..(you can see a icon in the right hand of the taskbar.It may be hide.so you can click the arrow which dhows you the hide apps runing).So click the icon and go to ***Mysql***

3.Then go to ***Service*** and there you can find ***Start/Resume Services*** click on it..
4.And now it is done.Open mysql workbench and see.It will work..

Answer (score 0):

You should create an specific user for accesing from your laptop:

```
CREATE USER 'youruser'@'machine.domain.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'youruser'@'machine.domain.com' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Or you could create an user for accesing from anywhere

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```